# Alerts for PCT application?

Tags: pct, google-patents, patentscope

Is there a way to get alerts on a PCT application, for example through [PatentScope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/) or Google Patents, which both list it? Unfortunately, freepatentsonline offers alerts but doesn't list the application, and I am not sure if Google Alerts will tell when an application becomes a granted patent, because the document numbers aren't the same. My goal is to get an email if the application is granted or denied. I can also work with RSS feed readers, if that's an option.

Comment: Between filing a PCT application and something getting granted there are a few steps. A PCT application is a bundle of applications to 144+ places. To end up with a patent in any of those places the local version of the PCT must enter a national (or regional) stage in that place. The number it is given in each locality is not the same as the PCT number. Granting/Issuing is a clearly defined event, a "denial" is not. Most application are rejected one or many times before finally going abandoned or being granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in getting emails about a PCT when there are any developments about the prosecution of the PCT itself or the European regional phase (if ever entered into, and the European regional phase **only**), you can monitor the PCT in that way through the [European Patent Register](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP20803803&tab=main) (linking to an exemplary PCT).

In the dark navigation bar at the top, on the right, there is a link that reads '*Register Alert (email alerts)*'. Once you are registered and logged in, once you are in the page of a PCT (or an EP application/patent), below the header '*About this file:*' there are several links, one of which is '*+Add*'. It will start monitoring that application and when there are any changes in it, you will receive an email informing you about the event and with a link to the actual communication.

While logged in the Alert service you will also have access to your private panel with all the applications you are monitoring and links to add/modify/delete monitored applications.

As I said before, if you monitor a PCT it will inform you about the developments of an eventual EP regional phase, but not about developments in other phases. The reason for this is because the EPO assigns an EP application number to all PCT applications, and when you monitor a PCT in this manner you are actually monitoring that particular EP application number. If it does not enter into the EP regional phase you will receive a notification that the application is deemed to be withdrawn, but perhaps it will have entered into the US national phase, the JP national phase, etc.

Comment: This will do the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[The Lens](https://www.lens.org) provides the ability to run saved queries if you create an account. I have it set up to check for patents issued with me as the inventor. It will send me an email if one of my applications get granted. I haven't tried alerts based on a specific document number, but I assume that would work too. The site allows very fine grained control of searches. Creating an account is completely free and The Lens doesn't seem to do any marketing with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The particular PCT application I am interested in is not listed, but I can see it is a useful search engine overall.

Comment: @KAE Thanks. Any particular document might take several days to a week to get into some of these third party services, but they generally do.